# Google analytic not showing any data

Tags: android, google-analytics

hi i am trying to add google analytic code into my app and i done it this way .

in gradle module level i added this :

```
dependencies {
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

and in my main activity i added this part of code:

```
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
```

and i started it in my on.create method in my activity like this

```
getDefaultTracker();
```

everything seems to be OK and i didn't get any errors but in my google analytic console i can see nothing that shows this code works even in real time users i have none and another point i cant upgrade the version of compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89' and it should stay at this version .

Comment: are there any errors in logs?

Comment: @AmodGokhale no i think i should add somting in project gradle dependencies like this classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: but when i do that i get this error Error:Execution failed for task ':locoFood:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: what version should i use